# expand.model.frame within lapply() & map(): environment confusion with fixest::feols and lm

Tags: r, lapply, environment

I am trying to use `expand.model.frame()` within `lapply()` after estimating models with both `lm` and `fixest::feols()`.

As it happens, I continuously run into errors for `fixest::feols`, likely because I am confused about environments.

Here's a prototypical example:

```
library(fixest) 
library(lfe)
library(estimatr)

fun <- function(object, clustid){
  
  fml <- object$call$formula
  if(!inherits(clustid, "formula")){
    clustid <- reformulate(clustid)
  }
  
  expand.model.frame(
    model = object, 
    extras = clustid, 
    #envir = environment(terms(object)),
    #envir = .GlobalEnv,
    na.expand = FALSE
  )
  
}

data(mtcars)

tmp_lm <- lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), function(x){lm(mpg ~ qsec ,data = x)})
lapply(tmp_lm, function(x) fun(x, clustid = "carb"))

tmp_feols <- lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), function(x){feols(mpg ~ qsec ,data = x)})
lapply(tmp_feols, function(x) fun(x, clustid = ~carb))
# Error in eval(model$call$data, envir) : object 'x' not found

tmp_felm <- lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), function(x){felm(mpg ~ qsec ,data = x)})
lapply(tmp_felm, function(x) fun(x, clustid = ~carb))

tmp_estimatr <- lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), function(x){lm_robust(mpg ~ qsec ,data = x)})
lapply(tmp_estimatr, function(x) fun(x, clustid = ~carb))
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I would have to tweak `fun()` so that I would no longer run into the error below?

Comment: Sorry, multiple typos in the question! I have now updated it. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: For `lm` you do not need first 4 lines of `fun` since [**`expand.model.frame`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/expand.model.frame) can receive a formula or character vector. Also, since this method and `lm` are in `stats` package, they likely work great together. However, inputting objects from the third-party packages (i.e., `fixest`) may not align properly.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait! object created by `feols()` do in fact have a `call$data` entry. Furthermore, I have tested other modeling package, `lfe` and `estimatr`, and only `fixest::feols()` seems to run into the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from your commented code that you have been experimenting with the `envir` argument. You are on the right track here. The "fixest" class contains an object called `call_env` to ensure you can access the correct evaluating environment. That means you need to alter your code to get the correct calling environment according to the type of object passed:

```r
fun <- function(object, clustid){

  if(!inherits(clustid, "formula")){
    clustid <- reformulate(clustid)
  }
  
  e <- if(class(object) == "fixest") 
    object$call_env else environment(formula(object))
  
  expand.model.frame(
    model = object, 
    extras = clustid, 
    envir = e,
    na.expand = FALSE
  )
  
}
```

This allows:

```r
data(mtcars)

tmp_feols <- lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), function(x){feols(mpg ~ qsec ,data = x)})
lapply(tmp_feols, function(x) fun(x, clustid = ~carb))
#> [[1]]
#>                      mpg  qsec carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0 16.46    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 17.02    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8 18.61    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 19.44    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7 17.02    2
#> Valiant             18.1 20.22    1
#> Duster 360          14.3 15.84    4
#> Merc 240D           24.4 20.00    2
#> Merc 230            22.8 22.90    2
#> Merc 280            19.2 18.30    4
#> Merc 280C           17.8 18.90    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4 17.40    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3 17.60    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2 18.00    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4 17.98    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4 17.82    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7 17.42    4
#> Fiat 128            32.4 19.47    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4 18.52    2
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9 19.90    1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5 20.01    1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5 16.87    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2 17.30    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3 15.41    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2 17.05    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3 18.90    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0 16.70    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4 16.90    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8 14.50    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7 15.50    6
#> Maserati Bora       15.0 14.60    8
#> Volvo 142E          21.4 18.60    2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                      mpg  qsec carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0 16.46    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 17.02    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8 18.61    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 19.44    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7 17.02    2
#> Valiant             18.1 20.22    1
#> Duster 360          14.3 15.84    4
#> Merc 240D           24.4 20.00    2
#> Merc 230            22.8 22.90    2
#> Merc 280            19.2 18.30    4
#> Merc 280C           17.8 18.90    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4 17.40    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3 17.60    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2 18.00    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4 17.98    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4 17.82    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7 17.42    4
#> Fiat 128            32.4 19.47    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4 18.52    2
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9 19.90    1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5 20.01    1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5 16.87    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2 17.30    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3 15.41    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2 17.05    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3 18.90    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0 16.70    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4 16.90    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8 14.50    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7 15.50    6
#> Maserati Bora       15.0 14.60    8
#> Volvo 142E          21.4 18.60    2
```

But will still work on the `lm` version.

Of course, a more sophisticated way to do this would be to create a new generic function that dispatches according to class, rather than handling classes inside one big function.

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the answer that I was looking for!